# How to add additionnal.jar for gmail sender in maven project's POM file?

Tags: android

How to add additionnal.jar for gmail sender in maven project's POM file?
I have added 2 jars : 1. Mail.jar
2. activation.jars dependency in POM.xml which are maven official jars.

However i am not able to add additionnal.jar dependency in POM.xml which is required for sending gmail, due to not addition of this jar i am getting the following exception 
"No class found exception javax.activation.dataHandler"

Answer (score 3):

You will need to download all 3 jars from the [javamail-android project](http://code.google.com/p/javamail-android/downloads/list) and then install them into your repo.

So for additionnal.jar, use something like -

```
> mvn install:install-file -Dfile=additionnal.jar -DgroupId=javamail-android -DartifactId=additionnal -Dversion=1.0.0 -Dpackaging=jar
```

Then add the dependency into your POM file -

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>javamail-android</groupId>
  <artifactId>additionnal</artifactId>
  <version>1.0.0</version>
</dependency>
```

This should then be repeated with appropriate modifications for the other two jar files.

Due to the inter-dependency between these jars, I don't believe you can mix the "official" versions of mail.jar and activation.jar with those from the javamail-android library.

Answer (score 1):

You can not add javax.* stuff to an android app without shading it. Look for a replacement. What are you trying to do?